# if tag not checking all classes and just finishes with checking the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

The problem I have is some divs with same class but different id like this and I have another `.icon` class that I want to compare the id with the ids of the box classes:

```
<div class="box" id="first" data-marker="first">

</div>

<div class="box" id="second" data-marker="second">

</div>

<div class="box" id="third" data-marker="third">

</div>

<div class="icon" id="first">

</div>

<div class="icon" id="second">

</div>
```

and I wrote a jQuery like this

```
$('.icon').on('click', function () {
    if($(this).attr("id") == $(".box").attr("data-marker")){
        value= $(this).attr("id");
        console.log("#" + value);
        $("#" + value ).addClass('active');
    }else{

    }
});
```

The problem is the if tag only checks the first box class for example if u click on icon class with the id of "second" it does not check other box and it only checks the box with the id of #first or better to say the first box,
and thats all

Comment: please make a jsfiddle with it. Your English isn't perfect and working jsfiddle would be helpful.

Comment: when is your script called?.

Comment: Please note that you should never have multiple elements with the same ID `id="first"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `.data()` or the `data` attribute, consider this code.

```js
$('.icon').on('click', function(e) {
  $("#" + $(this).data("rel")).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: #EEE;
}

.box.active {
  border: 1px solid #2F2;
}

.icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="box-1"></div>
<div class="box" id="box-2"></div>
<div class="box" id="box-3"></div>
<div class="icon" id="icon-1" data-rel="box-1"></div>
<div class="icon" id="icon-2" data-rel="box-2"></div>
```

The `.toggleClass()` can be very helpful for this type of activity.

**See More:**

- https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/
- https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/